# How to Associate Page Title with Author as Variable or Token or Relationship

Tags: views, tokens

I have created a custom content type for each of several contributing users for multi-blog purposes. I then used Views to create a page for each content type and thus a "blog home page" for each user.  I have also modified my theme's node.tpl.php file to reflect the custom look I want for displaying the teasers for all the custom content that is created.

The current header portion of my node.tpl.php file:

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <header>
<?php endif; ?>
<span class="uppercase">
  <span class="blog_title"></span>
  <span class="post_date"><? print " | "; ?></span><? print render($date); ?></span>
</span>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2 class="title" <?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <span class="submitted">By
    <span class="uppercase"><?php print $submitted; ?></span>
  </span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  </header>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can display the custom content title with $title, the date it was submitted by $date and the author by $submitted.  What I would like to include is the title/link to the page (that was created by the view of the custom content type associated with the author).

Is this something I can use relationships for to somehow generate a token and/or variable?

I don't really have any idea about how to approach this; any ideas or advice are much appreciate... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. In your theme template.php file add preprocess_node as below.
2. The below code will grab the author of current node for your custom content type.
3. And $node_author will be available to user on node.tpl.php
4. With the help of $node_author you can make the link

   ```
   //
   //Override or insert variables into the node template.
   //
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
     //dpm($variables);
     if($variables['type'] == 'my_custom_content_type') {
       $node_author = $variables['uid'];
       $variables['home_page'] = $node_author;
     }
   }
   ```
5. In your views add contextual filter for author uid to grab from url.
6. This should work for you.